# Concatenation in port mapping

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

Using Vivado 2015.2, VHDL.
Got a warning "[Synth 8-1565] actual for formal port b is neither a static name nor a globally static expression"

```
ADD1: Adder_32_33
PORT MAP (
A => a1,
B => a1&"0", -- warning here
CLK => clock,
S => s1
);
```

Sim works fine.
Can this warning be ignored ?
Is there any solution besides adding a new signal ?

Comment: Try defining a signal assigned with `a1&"0"` and mapping it to the port. It won't add any logical overhead and clear the warning.

Comment: Try setting the source's FILE_TYPE to VHDL2008. Click on it in Project Manager, go to the source file properties tab and change the FILE_TYPE to VHDL 2008.

Answer (score 3):

The warning is displayed because other VHDL tools, like the ModelSim VHDL simulator, do not support this type of port mapping (for signal B).

Another solution would be to use a sliced port mapping for `B`, e.g.:

```
ADD1: Adder_32_33
PORT MAP (
A => a1,
B(32 downto 1) => a1,  -- assign upper bits of B
B(0) => '0', -- assign (single) bit 0 of B only
CLK => clock,
S => s1
);
```

This assumes, that port B is declared with a range of `(32 downto 0)`.

Please note, that always all bits of a port must be assigned.

Comment: Perfectly resolved my own problem, thank you!